# Running gradle from docker: cannot get artifacts from maven repository

Tags: docker, spring-boot, gradle, dockerfile

I have a Spring Boot application with Gradle, and I want to create a docker image that would simply copy the project and do a gradle build. The Dockerfile is rather simple:

```
FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
VOLUME /tmp
ENTRYPOINT ./gradlew build --stacktrace
```

However, `docker run` fails **randomly** as it cannot download things from maven or jcenter repository. An example of such failure:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring project ':my-app'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':my-app:classpath'.
    > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE.
    Required by:
        project :my-app
    > Could not resolve org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.0.RELEASE.
        > Could not get resource 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-gradle-plugin/2.0.0.RELEASE/spring-boot-gradle-plugin-2.0.0.RELEASE.pom'.
               > repo1.maven.org
```

The computer is of course well connected to the internet and a gradle build outside of docker always runs successfully. Am I missing something fundamental here?

**UPDATE1:** The problem was solved by adding the following 2 lines in the `Dockerfile`:

```
ENV http_proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3001"
ENV https_proxy "http://127.0.0.1:3001"
```

Taken from https://docs.docker.com/network/proxy/

Does this mean that docker had some problems with my network's proxy server? And what does proxying `http://127.0.0.1:3001` exactly mean?

**UPDATE2:** Looks like adding `--dns 208.67.222.222 --dns 208.67.220.220` (telling docker to use OpenDNS) also resolves the problem. Now I'm really confused.

Comment: Be aware that `docker run` depends on where you're executing, because you're copying `.` to `/app`.